How to correctly torque Campagnolo (Ekar) shifter bolt
On Campagnolo Ekar (and possibly others), sometimes it is necessary to open and close again the central bolt inside the shifter that keeps the plastic "cap" on the central rotating shifting assembly, e.g. when the bead got stuck or for replacing the cable, e.g. as discussed previously here:

This bolt needs to be tightened to a very precise torque:

If it is too loose, you get ghost-upshifts as the derailleur spring is then stronger than the friction keeping the rotating assembly "locked", causing it to rotate on its own
If it is too tight, it's hard/impossible to shift.

Sometimes it's hard to tell from the symptoms whether the bolt is too tight or too loose. Unfortunately, the manual doesn't explain anything about this bolt. So the question is:
How to correctly torque this bolt without having to install and remove the shifter several times for try-and-error (which also implies re-doing the bar tape)?
